# Page 'loaded' event behavior explanation - difference between navigateTo() and goBack()

Tags: nativescript

I've got an app with a page xml definition that has a grid-layout with no children. During the page 'loaded' event, I create a bunch of child elements and add them to the grid-layout dynamically.

I navigate to another page and then call frameModule.topmost().goBack() to go back to the previous page.

On that main page, the 'loaded' event gets called again - BUT has the children I already added in the previous navigation - so looks like the page wasn't created again.

Interestingly, if from the same main page, I navigate to another page and then navigate back (i.e. w/o calling goBack()), then the 'loaded' event gets called but the page doesn't have the children I added - so looks like the page was freshly created.

My questions are:

1. When one calls goBack(), why is 'loaded' called on the previous page - even though it looks like the previously loaded page was being used.
2. Is this a bug?
3. Any way to determine in the 'loaded' function - whether this is truly a fresh page loaded or all elements have been created.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between goBack and Navigate is that goback just goes back up the navigation history stack, and acts the same as if the person hits the "back" button(android) or swipes to the right (iOS). Navigate goes forward and adds a new stack entry that you can `goBack` on.

Lets look at two examples:

So if I started on Page1 and Navigated to Page2, then Navigated to Page3 then the user hit my "< Back" button and in the code I then Navigated To Page1, my Navigation Stack would look like this:

`Page1
Page2
Page3
Page1`

If I then use the hardware back button (which triggers) `goBack` it will be Page3, then Page2, then Page1.  The user would probably not expect being on Page1 and hitting the back button to put them on Page3 rather than exiting.  So unless you are wanting a weird navigation; this would be normally considered unexpected/broken behavior.

Under proper navigation I might do this:

`Page1
Page2 (Not stored in History: used "backstackVisible: false")
Page3`

Then a `Back` from Page3 would actually put me in Page1, and a `Back` from Page 1 would exit the application.  This would be the expected behavior.

---

Now as to the events.
The events for this page are NavigatingTo, Loaded, NavigatedTo -- they fire in that order.

The loaded event being called is not a bug; it is by design; when the page component is loaded -- it allows you to be able to set up the page element.  All components have a "loaded" event.     So this is a component level event not a page navigation type event.    So for example; I've done this before:
`<Switch android:loaded="fixAndroidSwitch"/>` and then my `fixAndroidSwitch` routine fixed up something on the switch.

The NavigatingTo and NavigatedTo are actual Navigation events, and they do have a value passed as part of the argument:

`function onNavigatingTo(context) {
  if (context.isBackNavigation) { /* Do whatever */ }
}`

For more information on page events; you can read my Blog post http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=191 and it explains more

Comment: Is that isBack parameter documented anywhere. I'm navigating back to a page with goBack() and it's still undefined.

Comment: Sorry, isBack is used internally - I sometimes forget which part I'm dealing with.   LOL --  The args passed with the onNavigatedTo, onNavigatingTo have a "isBackNavigation" value.  (true or false)